# How to set path for PyGithub method?

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygithub

I'm working with PyGithub to get basic access to my own github repo.  Most methods require a "path" and I'm not sure what that is.  What parameters would I use in the .get_contents() function?  Simple example:

```
    from github import Github
    g = Github("***","***")
    repo = g.get_user().get_repo("my_projects")
    contents = repo.get_contents()
```

Comment: what  is the response you are getting for the above snippet?

Comment: traceback error; last 2 lines read:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyGithub-1.25.2-py2.7.egg/github/Requester.py", line 177, in __check
    raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.UnknownObjectException: 404 {u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3', u'message': u'Not Found'}

Comment: according to pygithhub above exception gets generated for below reason:    Exception raised when a non-existing object is requested (when Github API replies with a 404 HTML status)

Comment: the repo objects exists (i can call repo.name and get "my_projects" with no error). I need to figure out what to put in get_contents( ) I think

Comment: you can refer at https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/168

Comment: Check the scope of your user credentials. https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the following arguments:

**path** - *string* -   The content path.

**ref** -   *string* - The name of the commit/branch/tag. Default: the repository’s default branch (usually master)

E.g - `repo.get_contents('config/version.rb','development')`

See more [here](http://pygithub.github.io/PyGithub/v1/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_contents)